# Does Clang provide intrinsics for WebAssembly's memory.fill and memory.copy?

Tags: javascript, c, clang, llvm, webassembly

I'm working on developing a WebAssembly module in C and have been attempting to utilize the `memory.fill` and `memory.copy` instructions defined in the [WebAssembly spec](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/instructions.html#memory-instructions).

I know that Clang (v11.1.0) already [supports other memory-related wasm intrinsics](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/a6628e596e70bf5c31058dec582c8a7907928e98/clang/include/clang/Basic/BuiltinsWebAssembly.def#L25) like `__builtin_wasm_memory_size` and `__builtin_wasm_memory_grow`, but I've been having a hard time working out if it supports intrinsics for `memory.fill` and `memory.copy`.

I'm not intimately familiar with the inner workings of Clang/LLVM but references to these instructions seem to be hinted at in a few places [[1]](https://reviews.llvm.org/D57736#change-nNN3Qfkg9dIt) [[2]](https://reviews.llvm.org/D57791) (unless I'm misinterpreting something).

I attempted to use `__builtin_memcpy` and `__builtin_memset`:

```
__attribute__((export_name("memcpy")))
void memcpy_test(void* mem_dst, void* mem_src) {
    __builtin_memcpy(mem_dst, mem_src, 128);
}

__attribute__((export_name("memset")))
void memset_test(void* mem_src) {
    __builtin_memset(mem_src, 0, 128);
}
```

which compiles, but the calls to `__builtin_memcpy` and `__builtin_memset` are replaced with imported functions in the assembly:

```
...
  (import "env" "memcpy" (func $memcpy (type $t0)))
  (import "env" "memset" (func $memset (type $t0)))
  (func $__wasm_call_ctors (type $t1))
  (func $memcpy_test (type $t2) (param $p0 i32) (param $p1 i32)
    local.get $p0
    local.get $p1
    i32.const 128
    call $memcpy
    drop)
  (func $memset_test (type $t3) (param $p0 i32)
    local.get $p0
    i32.const 0
    i32.const 128
    call $memset
    drop)
...
```

At this point I'm a little stuck, it seems like these intrinsics aren’t available yet, but I’m not positive of that.

I'd really appreciate any help I could get!

*[Quick note: I'm not currently interested in using emscripten as I'm trying to avoid the large amount of glue code it comes with.]*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> but the calls to `__builtin_memcpy` and `__builtin_memset` are replaced with imported functions in the assembly:

The reason is that those instructions are not part of the core (MVP) WebAssembly instruction set, and were added later in the [bulk-memory proposal](https://github.com/WebAssembly/bulk-memory-operations).

Those later proposals need to be opted in explicitly, since there is a risk that a given WebAssembly engine you might be targeting is not supporting them yet. To be sure, you can check [my support table on webassembly.org](https://webassembly.org/roadmap/).

Finally, if you already checked this, you can opt in to this feature in Clang via `-mbulk-memory` flag. For example, with this flag and optimisations enabled

```sh
clang temp.c -mbulk-memory -O -c -o temp.wasm
```

this is what I get for your sample above:

```
(module
  (type $t0 (func (param i32 i32)))
  (type $t1 (func (param i32)))
  (import "env" "__linear_memory" (memory $env.__linear_memory 0))
  (import "env" "__indirect_function_table" (table $env.__indirect_function_table 0 funcref))
  (func $memcpy_test (type $t0) (param $p0 i32) (param $p1 i32)
    (memory.copy
      (local.get $p0)
      (local.get $p1)
      (i32.const 128)))
  (func $memset_test (type $t1) (param $p0 i32)
    (memory.fill
      (local.get $p0)
      (i32.const 0)
      (i32.const 128)))
  (export "memcpy" (func $memcpy_test))
  (export "memset" (func $memset_test)))
```

which seems to be the expected result.

Comment: This was exactly the problem! Great explanation, that makes complete sense. I knew the operations were relatively new, so I figured their browser support would be limited. It never dawned on me that they might have to be explicitly enabled. Thank you!