# WebAssembly wasm-ld cannot resolve __builtin_memcpy and __builtin_memset

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, webassembly

I'm working on a C++/Wasm-Module and have a hard time with **clang** and **wasm-ld**.

the toolchain lets me use **builtin functions** like

- __builtin_clz
- __builtin_floorf

just fine.
The following functions are accepted by clang, but cannot be resolved by wasm-ld.

- **__builtin_memcpy**
- **__builtin_memset**

```
wasm-ld: error: lto.tmp: undefined symbol: memcpy
```

below are the flags i pass to clang and wasm-ld in my makefile:
weird is, that even though i explicitly call the builtin function, clang emits the clib name.

```
// clang.exe
CLANGFLAGS = \
    -c \
    --target=wasm32 \
    -Os \
    -flto \
    --include-directory=.

//wasm-ld.exe
LDFLAGS = \
    -O3 \
    --no-entry \
    --strip-all \
    --export-dynamic \
    --lto-O3 \
    --gc-sections
    --std=c++20
```

what i have tried:

1. I thought, I could cheat and maybe use memset() and forward it to the builtin equivalent - this just ends in a stack-overflow because of an endless recursion. The method just calls itself over and over again.

```
extern "C" void* memset(void* pMemory, i32 value, size_t length) noexcept {
    return __builtin_memset(pMemory, value, length);
}
```

2. disable link time optimization -flto. Doesn't help. Error is now reported by clang instead of wasm-ld.
3. disabled all flags except --target=wasm32 and --no-entry. Nope...

Google didn't have a good advice 'til now. But maybe you guys do.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67084011

Comment: hmm very interesting indeed... I'll take a look

Comment: I think the answer in stackoverflow.com/a/67084011 is the key.

I'll try it out tonight and hopefully close this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I Confirm the suggestion by **Hasturkun**:

The memory builtins get enabled by -mbulk-memory. See [stackoverflow.com/a/67084011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67084011) for a more details.

clang -c --target=wasm32 **-mbulk-memory**